# How to make list items wrap content?

Tags: android

I have the following list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

The problem here is that if the list item contains a lot of text, not all of it is shown. Is there a way to make every list item high enough to show all of its content?

Comment: How you are adding listem to list and the xml that is used for each row

Comment: @DilSe I add it dynamically in the Java code, with `listItems.add(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I've found is to create an XML file specifically for list rows. This way, the list item automatically adjusts its height to show all the text. This XML file is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</TextView>
```

Changing `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` doesn't make any different, it works in both ways.

Now I simply need to tell the adapter to use this file for the layout instead of the default one.

Answer (score 2):

you must create row xml and customize the hight as you want depend on what you have on each row.
as follow :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/Layout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="15dp"  />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you should set layout_height of your LinearLayout to "wrap_content".

Comment: already check it will not affect the change in LinearLayout it self, but the trick on changing the android:layout_height of TextView , also you can customize the textSize depend on what you need

Comment: you already mentioned on your question : ( if the list item contains a lot of text, not all of it is shown) , explane more please ,thanks

Comment: What I mean is that if the list item contains short text (say, a single word) everything is ok. If the list item contains a long text (for example, more than two rows of text), I can only see the first two rows.

Comment: if you mean to do it in java i think this will solve it , do as follow : LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = someLayout.getLayoutParams(); params.height = "any size you want"; someLayout.setLayoutParams(params); . hope this helpful

Comment: This is ok, but in this case I have to hardcode the height I want. What if I have some lines with short text and some others with long text? Isn't there a way to make the list automatically calculate the height of the list row based on the amount of text?

Comment: im not sure my friend but , if you use custom adapter my solve that,

Comment: For some reason, what you suggested didn't work. I found an easier solution (you can check my answer if you are interested). Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should set height of list items, not `ListView` by itself

Comment: Exactly my question :) How can I do it?

Comment: The article does not talk about BaseAdapter, I'm probably missing something here :D

Comment: @user1301428, oh, I'm sorry. Here is correct link ) http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using listview to show list items i suggest you to use CustomAdapter to do so,

Here is the [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom) for a sample example to implement

Comment: Would this solve my problem? I'm asking you because I only know about a difference in performance between the two.